# Best way to describe a decrease in time taken?

Tags: expression-choice, science

I have written an algorithm that greatly improves the computation time for a particular problem, but I am divided on how to best describe this in writing. As a rough guide, a process that previously took 20 seconds will now only require 1 second under the new approach. Based upon both clarity and punchiness, which is the best way to describe this out of the following:

> - a 95% reduction in computation time
> - a 20x speed-up in computation time
> - a better unspecified option

Comment: Both of your examples are comparisons. What is the second, or implicit, thing that you are comparing to?

Comment: In the example given I am comparing the original time (20 seconds) to the improved time (1 second).

Comment: Other than what you've mentioned (and the converses) there's not really a better way to put it.  Which one you want to use is really up to you and what you want to emphasize.

Comment: I've heard that there is a psychological benefit to emphasizing one over the other (savings vs. improved speed) but I don't know specifically which is perceived as better so maybe this is a good question for another SE site?

Comment: Speeding up, acceleration.

Comment: Not saying it's better, but another alternative is:  Now runs in 1/20th the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a programmer, you realize that if the audience is somewhat non-technical, they may not care about"computation time", but rather in perceived performance.
You might write,

> ".. a 2000% increase in performance"

If they *are* comfortable with terms like computation time, you could say,

> "uses 5% of the computation time required previously"

Answer (score 1):

I personally use language like: *We achieved a 20x speedup with the new algorithm.*